# PHP OOP. How to get value of constant __METHOD__ of class what create an instance of other class inside that other class?

Tags: php, class, oop

We have class A and class B.
class B have a public property $class_a.
few functions few functions of class B can set `$this->class_a = new A(__METHOD__);`
I need to know value of Class B **__METHOD__** inside class A.
Now I'm using inside class A:

```
public function __construct($owner_method){
//some code..
}
```

is it possible not to pass this parameter during construct?

Is it possible to access such constants of "class owner" when I'm inside that class A ?

Comment: What do you need to do with the class B method? Know its name as a string? Call it from class A?

Comment: Need to read a value of it inside class A. Class A is class of "logs system" and I want to monitor which class::method put some notification message. I want to simplify __construct() method and not to pass that constant as argument. (to read a method of class owner inside it instance)

Comment: I think you need to pass it as you are currently doing. [`get_parent_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) exists but that is for when you are extending objects, which you are not doing, so passing it seems not only the only option but also more proper and reusable to me.

Comment: yes, it only works if class is extended.. But I need if instance is created.

Comment: You need to pass it in then.

Comment: post this as answer, and I'll mark this question closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass it as you are currently doing. [`get_parent_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) exists but that is for when you are extending objects, which you are not doing, so passing it seems not only the only option but also more proper and reusable to me.

In short: no, you need to carry on passing it in, whether in the constructor or the individual `log` method.

Comment: And I agree with that as well : )

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think that better solution would be to instantiate that "logging system" class once, pass it to other classes as an argument (`DI`) and then on each logging action you can can use some method to do the job. That way you have clean `__construct`.

```
class A
{
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function log($owner_method) {
        //job
    }
}
```

There is no way to know which class instantiated class `A`, well, maybe, by parsing stacktrace - but thats odd.

Comment: I agree. Didn't know how the logger class behaves though though, so didn't go there.

Answer (score 0):

This is my class For writing logs:

```
class Dll_Log {

    protected $data = array();
    protected $function = NULL;
    private $path = FALSE;

    public function __construct($function){
        $function = str_replace('::','-',$function);
        $this->function = $function;
        $this->path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'assets'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'log'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    public function set($data){
        $this->data = array_merge((array)$this->data, (array)$data);
        return $this;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        if(WRITE_LOG AND (count($this->data)>0)){
            $this->data = array('data'=>$this->data, 'time'=>date("H:i:s"));
            $file = $this->path.date("Y-m-d").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->function;
            $dirname = dirname($file);
            if (!is_dir($dirname)){
                mkdir($dirname, 0755, true);
            }
            $f = fopen ($file, 'a+' );
            flock ( $f, LOCK_EX );
            fwrite($f,json_encode($this->data).PHP_EOL);
            flock ( $f, LOCK_UN );
            fclose ( $f );
        }
    }
```

So when I'm debugging some classes For example class B, method load_page:
I must to do next:

```
Class B{
public function load_page(){
    $logger = New Dll_Log(__METHOD__);
    if( ($x = do_something()) !==false)
        $logger->set(array('x-val-problem'=>'$x received FALSE value'));
    if( ($y = do_something_other()) !==false)
        $logger->set(array('y-val-problem'=>'$y received FALSE value'));
    if( ($z = do_something_else()) !==false)
        $logger->set(array('z-val-problem'=>'$z received FALSE value'));
    try{
         SomeClass::SomeMethod($x,$y,$z);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $logger->set(array('GOT_EXCEPTION'=>$e));
    }
}
}
```

AS  you see, each time when I `$logger = New Dll_Log(__METHOD__);` - it's little not comfortable. `$logger = New Dll_Log();` will be eaiser and it can guarantee that third-party classes will not able to falsificate LOG data..
Will be great if php have  **get_owner_class**, not only `get_parent_class`.. :(

Comment: You can't do that, you **have** to pass it in.